# vb.net & command line: spaces in path to decrypt with GnuPG

Tags: vb.net, terminal, gnupg

I have been struggling with this problem for some time now. I am trying to decrypt a file in vb.net using GnuPG. I am able to successfully decrypt the file if its path has NO space. However when there is a space, GnuPG returns an error. I have no idea how I should structure my string with spaces for GnuPG to be able to handle it.

This is my code so far..

```
Dim runDate As date
Dim destFolder As String
Dim fullName As String
Dim cmdShellTemp As String

destFolder = """\\srvDat\DATA\ORTSS\RECON\ASTD rem\"""

fullName = runDate.ToString("yyyyMMdd") & "myFile.pdf.pgp"
cmdShellTemp = "gpg --batch --passphrase """ & pgpPassphrase & """ --decrypt-files """ & destFolder & fullName & """"
cmdShell = cmdShellTemp.Replace("\", "/")
Shell(cmdShell)
```

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### EDIT

---

After looking at the PGP command line documentation - it specifies that any files supplied to the `decrpyt` command are treated as space delimited. With this in mind you can't achieve your goal when supplying the entire path (unless the path contains no spaces). You will need to start the command prompt in the directory that contains the files instead and refer to them relatively.

[Page 69 of the instruction manual states](https://symwisedownload.symantec.com/resources/sites/SYMWISE/content/live/DOCUMENTATION/6000/DOC6232/en_US/pgpCmdline_103_usersguide_en.pdf?__gda__=1452140764_58075aff84d5467882ed37efa3495b6a):

> Decrypts encrypted files with local keys or keys on a PGP KMS server. If data being decrypted is also signed, the signature is automatically verified during the decryption process.
>
> The usage format is:
>   `pgp --decrypt <input> [<input2> ...] [<inputd>...] [options]`
>
> Where:
>   `<input>` (required). **Space-separated names of the files to decrypt.**

---

*(original answer geared towards string concatenation):*

It should allow quotes around the path even when there aren't spaces, so perhaps just enforce the quotation marks anyway. Try this instead:

```
Dim runDate As date
Dim destFolder As String
Dim fullName As String
Dim cmdShellTemp As String

destFolder = "\\srvDat\DATA\ORTSS\RECON\ASTD rem\" '// note the removed quote marks

fullName = runDate.ToString("yyyyMMdd") & "myFile.pdf.pgp"
cmdShellTemp = "gpg --batch --passphrase """ & pgpPassphrase & """ --decrypt-files """ & destFolder & fullName & """"
cmdShell = cmdShellTemp.Replace("\", "/")
Shell(cmdShell)
```

---

Ultimately the issue was with your quotes - you added them twice:

```
destFolder = """\\srvDat\DATA\ORTSS\RECON\ASTD rem\"""
```

would produce `"\\srvDat\DATA\ORTSS\RECON\ASTD rem\"` and:

```
cmdShellTemp = "gpg --batch --passphrase """ & pgpPassphrase & """ --decrypt-files """ & destFolder & fullName & """"
```

would end up with something like:

> `gpg --batch --passphrase "pass123" --decrpyt-files ""\\srvDat\DATA\ORTSS\RECON\ASTD rem\"20120105myFile.pdf.pgp"`

Which produces unwanted quotes within the file path

Comment: This solution does not work for me. GnuPG returns an error (gpg: can't open file). The issue is really the space. When I have the quotes twice and no space in the path ( destFolder= """\\srvDat\DATA\ORTSS\RECON\ASTD_rem\""" ), the code works just fine and decrypts the file.

Comment: Print the variable `cmdShell` to a console - what does it actually produce?

Comment: Thanks that helps a lot. Any idea how I can start shell in a specific directory? Or navigate to the directory before running the decryption?

Comment: Bad news time - you can't. cmd.exe can be strarted in another directory, but not from a UNC path - you will get an error stating the path is not valid and  it will default to the windows directory. My advice would be to copy the files locally and decrypt them from there.